# Trying to run a code in SML - error?

Tags: emacs, standards, sml, ml

I get an error when trying to run this sml-code in eMacs, and can't figure out what went wrong? Please help?

```
 fun nearest(a,[]) = raise Empty
  | nearest(a,t::[]) = route(a,t)
  | nearest(a,t::s) =  Real.min(route(a,t), nearest(a,s);
```

the error in SML:

```
  | nearest(a,t::s) =  Real.min(route(a,t), nearest(a,s);   
!                                                                             ^
! Syntax error.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Real.min is missing a closing paren.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are missing a paren as bnbeckwith said.
Unfortunately mosml doesn't have the best errormessages.

More pedantically, Emacs doesn't "run" your code, Emacs is just your editor and you are actually using mosml to run your code. Using sml-mode you can integrate mosml into Emacs to make development easier.

But please, we have an entire forum for you at absalon, and TAs/instructors willing to help there.